# Python: Nice way to iterate over shell command result

Tags: python, shell, command, exec

is there a "nice" way to iterate over the output of a shell command?

I'm looking for the python equivalent for something like:

```
ls | while read file; do
    echo $file
done
```

Note that 'ls' is only an example for a shell command which will return it's result in multiple lines and of cause 'echo' is just: do something with it.

I known of these alternatives: [Calling an external command in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/calling-an-external-command-in-python) but I don't know which one to use or if there is a "nicer" solution to this. (In fact "nicer" is the main focus of this question.)

This is for replacing some bash scripts with python.

Comment: beware of [block buffering issue](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20503671/4279) and [methods to fix it](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20509641/4279)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

you can open a pipe ( see [doc](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.popen) ):

```
import os

with os.popen('ls') as pipe:
    for line in pipe:
        print (line.strip())
```

as in the document this syntax is depreciated and is replaced with more complicated `subprocess.Popen`

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
pipe = Popen('ls', shell=True, stdout=PIPE)

for line in pipe.stdout:
    print(line.strip())
```

Comment: drop `shell=True`. It is unnecessary here.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian the necessity of `shell=True` depends on the bash scripts the OP is supposed to replace; for commands as simple as `ls ~`, it is necessary to pass `shell=True`

Answer (score 0):

[check_output](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) will give you back a string you can parse. `call` will simply re-use your existing stdout/stderr/stdin and simply return the process exit code.