# Python C program subprocess hangs at "for line in iter"

Tags: python, c, subprocess, freeze

Ok so I'm trying to run a C program from a python script. Currently I'm using a test C program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    while (1) {
        printf("2000\n");
        sleep(1);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

To simulate the program that I will be using, which takes readings from a sensor constantly.
Then I'm trying to read the output (in this case `"2000"`) from the C program with subprocess in python:

```
#!usr/bin/python
import subprocess

process = subprocess.Popen("./main", stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
while True:
    for line in iter(process.stdout.readline, ''):
            print line,
```

but this is not working. From using print statements, it runs the `.Popen` line then waits at `for line in iter(process.stdout.readline, ''):`, until I press Ctrl-C.

Why is this? This is exactly what most examples that I've seen have as their code, and yet it does not read the file.

Is there a way of making it run only when there is something to be read?

Comment: drop `while True`. Once the `for`-loop ended; you won't get anything from `process.stdout` anymore.

Comment: I think the answer should be changed to J.F. Sebastians Version. See my comment there why.

Comment: Thanks @Scheintod, good point.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

It is a block buffering issue.

What follows is an extended for your case version of my answer to [Python: read streaming input from subprocess.communicate()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17698359/4279) question.

### Fix stdout buffer in C program directly

`stdio`-based programs as a rule are line buffered if they are running interactively in a terminal and block buffered when their stdout is redirected to a pipe. In the latter case, you won't see new lines until the buffer overflows or flushed.

To avoid calling `fflush()` after each `printf()` call, you could force line buffered output by calling in a C program at the very beginning:

```
setvbuf(stdout, (char *) NULL, _IOLBF, 0); /* make line buffered stdout */
```

As soon as a newline is printed the buffer is flushed in this case.

#### Or fix it without modifying the source of C program

There is `stdbuf` utility that allows you to change buffering type without modifying the source code e.g.:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

process = Popen(["stdbuf", "-oL", "./main"], stdout=PIPE, bufsize=1)
for line in iter(process.stdout.readline, b''):
    print line,
process.communicate() # close process' stream, wait for it to exit
```

There are also other utilities available, see [Turn off buffering in pipe](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/25372/1321).

### Or use pseudo-TTY

To trick the subprocess into thinking that it is running interactively, you could use [`pexpect` module](http://pexpect.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) or its analogs, for code examples that use `pexpect` and `pty` modules, see [Python subprocess readlines() hangs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12471855/4279). Here's a variation on the `pty` example provided there (it should work on Linux):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import pty
import sys
from select import select
from subprocess import Popen, STDOUT

master_fd, slave_fd = pty.openpty()  # provide tty to enable line buffering
process = Popen("./main", stdin=slave_fd, stdout=slave_fd, stderr=STDOUT,
                bufsize=0, close_fds=True)
timeout = .1 # ugly but otherwise `select` blocks on process' exit
# code is similar to _copy() from pty.py
with os.fdopen(master_fd, 'r+b', 0) as master:
    input_fds = [master, sys.stdin]
    while True:
        fds = select(input_fds, [], [], timeout)[0]
        if master in fds: # subprocess' output is ready
            data = os.read(master_fd, 512) # <-- doesn't block, may return less
            if not data: # EOF
                input_fds.remove(master)
            else:
                os.write(sys.stdout.fileno(), data) # copy to our stdout
        if sys.stdin in fds: # got user input
            data = os.read(sys.stdin.fileno(), 512)
            if not data:
                input_fds.remove(sys.stdin)
            else:
                master.write(data) # copy it to subprocess' stdin
        if not fds: # timeout in select()
            if process.poll() is not None: # subprocess ended
                # and no output is buffered <-- timeout + dead subprocess
                assert not select([master], [], [], 0)[0] # race is possible
                os.close(slave_fd) # subproces don't need it anymore
                break
rc = process.wait()
print("subprocess exited with status %d" % rc)
```

#### Or use `pty` via `pexpect`

`pexpect` wraps `pty` handling into [higher level interface](http://pexpect.readthedocs.org/en/latest/overview.html):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import pexpect

child = pexpect.spawn("/.main")
for line in child:
    print line,
child.close()
```

[Q: Why not just use a pipe (popen())?](http://pexpect.readthedocs.org/en/latest/FAQ.html#whynotpipe) explains why pseudo-TTY is useful.

Comment: I think this Answer should be flagged as correct because it is the most complete, concise and offeres a variety of possible solutions and further readings. (It's a great answer.) But I really think in order for readers to process this dense information it absolutely needs some kind of headlines between the different approaches. I think most people see the big python block and get scared away before realizing it's just one of many possible solutions.

Comment: @Scheintod: I've added section headers. I'll be honest: I've answered this question because I wanted to play with `pty`, `select`. btw, you can [edit the answer yourself](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/20509641/edit) if it doesn't make it noticably worse.

Comment: Do you know of any similar solutions for output buffering on Windows?

Comment: @kuchi I don't know

Comment: @kuchi take a look at [pywinpty](https://github.com/spyder-ide/pywinpty). I don't know if that answers your question or not, but it appears to do something like pty, but for windows.

Comment: I think in the 2nd example the `bufsize=1` argument was being silently ignored. It now reports /usr/local/lib/python3.10/subprocess.py:961: RuntimeWarning: line buffering (buffering=1) isn't supported in binary mode, the default buffer size will be used` - the lack of warning has been fixed in https://bugs.python.org/issue32236

Comment: @DavidWaterworth the print statement in the code in the answer indicates Python 2 is used. I/O is reworked in Python 3 (from C stdio to POSIX read/write). The changes regarding bytes vs Unicode, corresponding changes in buffering for the pipes are expected. The parts of the answer regarding buffering in the child process should stand (unrelated to Python)

Comment: @jfs thanks for the clarification - I didn't notice it was py27.

Answer (score 6):

Your program isn't hung, it just runs very slowly. Your program is using buffered output; the `"2000\n"` data is not being written to stdout immediately, but will eventually make it. In your case, it might take `BUFSIZ/strlen("2000\n")` seconds (probably 1638 seconds) to complete.

After this line:

```
printf("2000\n");
```

add

```
fflush(stdout);
```

Comment: Thanks Rob, was just going to add that so he could see it faster. @theoB610, note you still need the newline.

Answer (score 4):

See [readline docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html#io.TextIOBase.readline).

Your code:

```
process.stdout.readline
```

Is waiting for EOF or a newline.

I cannot tell what you are ultimately trying to do, but adding a newline to your printf, e.g., `printf("2000\n");`, should at least get you started.