# Can't get anything from the stdout of a child process

Tags: c, node.js, parent-child, stdout

I'm trying to make a very simple nodejs server that receives post requests and feeds them to a simple C program that makes all of its I/O through stdin and stdout. I'm trying to use the following script as a test:

```
var prc = require('child_process').spawn('./example');

// )none of these made it work)
prc.stdout.setEncoding('ascii');
//prc.stdout.setEncoding('utf8');

prc.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
    console.log("child said something: " + data);
});

prc.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
    console.log("stderr: " + data.toString());
});

prc.on('close', function (code) {
    console.log('process exit code ' + code);
});

setInterval(function() {
    console.log("gonna write");
    prc.stdin.write("prueba inicial\n");
    console.log("wrote");
}, 2000);
```

`example.c` contains:

```
int main() {
    int i;
    size_t size;
    char *line = NULL;

    for (i=0;;++i) {
        printf("\ngive me data: ");
        if (getline(&line, &size, stdin) != -1) {
            if (strcmp(line, "end\n") == 0) {
                break;
            }
            printf("result: %d, %d\n", i, i*2);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

But the only thing I get on screen is

```
gonna write
wrote
gonna write
wrote
gonna write
wrote
```

I know `example` is running, but why am I not getting anything trough `prc.stdout`?

PD: may be it would be better to use sockets or something else to communicate with `example`, but this is just a test for a real project in which I'll be using another C program that I can't change.

Comment: Have you checked the return value of `prc.stdin.write`?  It may be buffering.  You may also want to listen to the `exit` event on the `ChildProcess`.

Comment: @AaronDufour It returns true, signifying the data was completely sent.

Comment: related: [Python C program subprocess hangs at “for line in iter”](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20503671/4279)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reason for needing `fflush(stdout)` is, because `stdio` detects you're not running in terminal, it will by default not flush on `'\n'`, for improved data throughput.

So you can flush explicitly, or you change the buffering mode in your C code simply with

```
setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IOLBF, 0);
```

Read [this man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/setbuf.3.html) to learn more about this.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently what fixed it was flushing `stdout` after every `printf`:

```
printf("result: %d, %d\n", i, i*2); 
fflush(stdout);
```

I tried that after seeing that the nodejs script got all the outputs when example.c was closed (by sending it `end\n`).