# Controlling a "daemon-like" linux script from Python

Tags: python, linux

I am trying to:

- execute a Linux script from Python
- wait for an interval
- kill the script (from Python) and get it's output (in Python)

I have played around with the subprocess library, however all functions which handle output are blocking (they wait for the process to terminate). However, in my particular case, the script is non-terminating.

Is there a way to run the script "in background", kill it after some time, and then obtain it's output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look at the [Popen Objects](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-objects) in [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html), they are completely appropriate for what you want to do:

```
import subprocess, time, signal

p = subprocess.Popen(['python', '-u', 'myscript.py'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
time.sleep(5)
p.send_signal(signal.SIGTERM)
output = p.communicate()[0]

print('Process has exited with code %d' % p.wait())
print('Output is %s' % str(output))
```

If you send a signal to stop the process, some data may be lost in the process output buffer. This is why you may want to ensure the script is not buffering its output (use "-u" option as above if your script is also a python script).

Comment: Thank you for answering! My problem is that indeed, my script is buffering it's output, and it is not a python script (it is a Click script, but this is less important). Is there a way to flush the output from Python?

Comment: The easiest and preferred method is to disable buffering from the Click script. If this is not possible, you should look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/20509641/42127 for other options.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, disabling buffering in Click was not an option (as far as I could figure out). To address the issue with scripts buffering their output, I opted for:

Writing a script (which I call `finite_script.sh`) running my program (`script.sh`) for a finite amount of time (and redirecting stderr to stdout):

```
#!/bin/bash
$1 2>&1 & 
sleep 5
kill -KILL `pgrep $1`
```

... and running the (terminating) `finite_script.sh` script in Python:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(['finite_script.sh', 'script.sh'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
(output, err) = p_real.communicate()
print output
```

The solution is not really elegant, but it works in my particular setting (where script.sh is actually a Click script).

Thank you for the previous answer!