# Live reading / writing to a subprocess stdin/stdout

Tags: python, io, subprocess

I want to make a Python wrapper for another command-line program.

I want to read Python's `stdin` as quickly as possible, filter and translate it, and then write it promptly to the child program's `stdin`.

At the same time, I want to be reading as quickly as possible from the child program's `stdout` and, after a bit of massaging, writing it promptly to Python's `stdout`.

The Python subprocess module is full of warnings to use `communicate()` to avoid deadlocks.  However, `communicate()` doesn't give me access to the child program's `stdout` until the child has terminated.

Comment: please post a snippet of how you are attempting, thnx.

Comment: @user1269942 I don't know which API to use.  Reading through `subprocess`, none of them fit.

Comment: related to the buffering issue: [Python C program subprocess hangs at “for line in iter”](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20503671/4279)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll be fine (carefully) ignoring the warnings using `Popen.stdin`, etc yourself.  Just be sure to process the streams line-by-line and iterate through them on a fair schedule so not to fill up any buffers.  A relatively simple (and inefficient) way of doing this in Python is using separate threads for the three streams.  That's how `Popen.communicate` does it internally.  Check out its source code to see how.

Comment: As noted by @Vorticity below, programs attached to a PIPE usually buffer their output.  To get around this, I used `pty.openpty` to create a master slave for the child's stdout.  You set the subprocess.Popen's stdout to the slave, and use a thread to read from the master.

Comment: @Will Oh, okay, that was your problem.  Sorry, I didn't get that but your solution sounds good.

Comment: @Will: Don't ignore the warning unless you understand it very well otherwise a program that passes all tests may hang in production (it is not hard to understand, just make sure that you do). `.communicate()` uses threads only on Windows otherwise a [select loop is used](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Lib/subprocess.py#l1603)

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian thx for the warning.  I am now on top of the situation.  I know what's happening under the hood.

Answer (score 1):

**Disclaimer:** This solution likely requires that you have access to the source code of the process you are trying to call, but may be worth trying anyways.  It depends on the called process periodically flushing its `stdout` buffer which is not standard.

Say you have a process `proc` created by `subprocess.Popen`.  `proc` has attributes `stdin` and `stdout`.  These attributes are simply file-like objects.  So, in order to send information through `stdin` you would call `proc.stdin.write()`.  To retrieve information from `proc.stdout` you would call `proc.stdout.readline()` to read an individual line.

**A couple of caveats:**

- When writing to `proc.stdin` via `write()` you will need to end  the input with a newline character.  Without a newline character, your subprocess will hang until a newline is passed.
- In order to read information from `proc.stdout` you will need to make sure that the command called by subprocess appropriately flushes its stdout buffer after each print statement and that each line ends with a newline.  If the stdout buffer does not flush at appropriate times, your call to `proc.stdout.readline()` will hang.

Comment: I found I could trick most child programs by giving them a `pty.openpty()` stdout.  This tricks them into doing line-buffering rather than big block buffering.