# How to stream subprocess output with a user prompt?

Tags: python, subprocess

Here's my subprocess call:

```
def myrun(cmd):
  p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
  stdout = []
    while True:
      line = p.stdout.readline()
      stdout.append(line)
      print line,
      if line == '' and p.poll() != None:
          break
  return ''.join(stdout)
```

When I run the 'cmd' normally, the output is usually something like:

*some text...*
*some more text...*
***Do you want to continue [yes/no]? : y***
*more output...*

But running the same 'cmd' with subprocess as shown above, my output is like this:

***Do you want to continue [yes/no]? : y***
*some text...*
*some more text...*
*more output...*

How do I fix this?

Comment: who enters `y` in this case? See [Python: read streaming input from subprocess.communicate()](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17698359/4279). Read the links provided there: using `pty` should fix the output written outside of stdout/stderr and the bufferring issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is basically because of the buffering that is there normally at whatever your `cmd` program has. You have to disable the default buffering happening at that program in order to attain what you are looking for.

In case it is a python file you are running through the cmd like the following, you can add `"-u"` parameter with the python command to get your desired result

```
cmd = ["python", "-u", "/link/to/python/file.py"]
myrun(cmd)
```

As per the man docs of python,

```
-u     : unbuffered binary stdout and stderr; also PYTHONUNBUFFERED=x
```

In case of any file that is to run in the shell, I would say `stdbuf` command is your safe bet. Set the `-o` option to 0(zero) along with the command and you are good to go.

```
cmd = ["sh", "\path\to\sh\file.sh"]
unbuffered_cmd = ["stdbuf", "-o0", "-e0"] + cmd
myrun(unbuffered_cmd)
```

Please note that [stdbuf](http://linux.die.net/man/1/stdbuf) comes with GNU coreutils. So it may not be platform agnostic.

To be on the safer side even with `stdbuf` present and `"-u"` set for python, set the `bufsize` parameter of Popen to 1

```
Popen(cmd, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT, bufsize=1)
```

I am out of options, if `stdbuf` is also not helping :-)

Comment: Thanks! stdbuf appears to do the trick in ordering! But now I've run into an issue where it waits for the user prompt before displaying the prompt message.

Comment: @nerdinary: if the child process writes the prompt directly to the terminal then trying to affect its stdout buffer (using `-u` or `stdbuf`) won't help. See [`pty`, `pexpect` solutions](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20509641/4279) instead.