# subprocess.Popen communicate with timeout, python 3

Tags: python, subprocess, timeout, popen

I'm trying to get the output of another process in python3

Here si my code

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(BIN, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
try:
    outs = proc.communicate(timeout=10)[0]
except subprocess.TimeoutExpired:
    proc.kill()
    outs = proc.communicate()[0]
```

The problem is :

BIN is an executable that never finish, so TimeoutExpired is always raised. But I'm unabled to get the output in the except block

Comment: what does *"unable to get the output"* mean? Is the output empty? Make sure it is not a [block buffering issue (the subprocess should flush its internal stdout buffers before we can read anything on our end)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20503671/4279).

Comment: mean the output is empty : b''

Comment: have you checked that the subprocess flushes its stdout buffers before the timeout?