# Process in python - fetch stdout of non-terminating process

Tags: python, subprocess, stdout

Suppose there is a program that produces different outputs with different inputs, and terminates if the input is a specific value. For example, it can be written in C++:

```
int main() {
    int i;
    while(true) {
        cin >> i;
        if (i) cout << i << endl;
        else break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

In this program, if you type a integer, it will print it on the screen. The program never terminates until you type a `0`.

Then how can I fetch the stdout corresponding to a stdin immediately with Python? That is, if I give a '1' into the stdin, I will expect to fetch a '1' from the stdout at once, while the process hasn't terminated yet.

---

Conclusion: There are two way to implement this.

1. Use `subprocess.Popen`, and treat stdout or stdin of the subprocess as a file, write into stdin (`'\n'` is needed), and read from stdout with `readline`
2. Use a library pexpect.

Comment: Can't you just read the stdout of the subprocess?

Comment: For those of us who don't read C++, you should mention what that output looks like; specifically, is it terminated with a newline?

Comment: If use `subprocess.Popen` module, and read directly, it will keep waiting and do nothing.

Comment: don't put an answer into your question. You may post your own answer if you'd like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `subprocess.Popen()`:

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> p = subprocess.Popen(['/your/cpp/program'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
>>> p.stdin.write('1\n')
>>> p.stdout.readline()
'1\n'
>>> p.stdin.write('10\n')
>>> p.stdout.readline()
'10\n'
>>> p.stdin.write('0\n')
>>> p.stdout.readline()
''
>>> p.wait()
0
```

Comment: there could be [buffering issues in the child](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20503671/4279) (there is none due to implicit flush on `endl` in this case) and in the parent (your script). The latter you could fix using `p.stdin.flush()` or `bufsize=1` on Python 3 where `bufsize` is non-zero by default.