# Java read process output unbuffered / realtime

Tags: java, process, progress-bar, stdout

I want to read the stdout of a process right as it is generated.
The process will send information for a progress indicator, so it doesn't make sense that I get the information all at once, which I do and which is the problem. I tried to use Scanner class as suggested in a post, but I still get the output only after the process has finished.
I realize this question has been asked before, but it hasn't been answered.

You will probably want to look at class StreamGobblerOutput first.

```
    public List<String> executeCall(String fileName) 
    {
    StringBuilder sbOutput = new StringBuilder();
    StringBuilder sbError = new StringBuilder();

    File file = new File(fileName);
    try ( BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file)) ) {
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
           String [] parts = line.split("\\s");
           if(parts.length<2) {
               sbError.append("Command too short for call: " + parts[0]);
               continue;
           }

            List<String> args = new ArrayList<String>();
            args.add ("sfb.exe");
            for(int i = 1; i <parts.length; ++i) {
                args.add (parts[i]);
            }
            args.add (sfbPassword);

            ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder (args);
            pb.directory(new File(Support.getJustThePathFromFile(file)));
            Map<String, String> envs = pb.environment();
            String path = envs.get("Path");
            envs.put("Path", Paths.get(".").toAbsolutePath().normalize().toString() + ";" +path);


            //pb.redirectOutput(new Redirect() {});
            Process p = pb.start();

            String outputPathPrefix = pb.directory().getCanonicalPath();

            // any output?
            StreamGobblerOutput outputGobbler = new StreamGobblerOutput(p.getInputStream(), outputPathPrefix);
            outputGobbler.start();

            // any errors?
            StreamGobblerError errorGobbler = new StreamGobblerError(p.getErrorStream());
            errorGobbler.start();


            try
            {
                p.waitFor();
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            sbOutput = outputGobbler.getOutput();
            sbError = errorGobbler.getErrors();

            String rootPath= Support.getJustThePathFromFile(new File(fileName));
            File rootFile = new File(rootPath + "/..");
            String rootFolder = rootFile.getCanonicalFile().getName();
            System.err.println("rootFolder: " + rootFolder);
            mainApp.addModifiedFiles(outputGobbler.getModifiedFileNames(), rootFolder);

        }
    } catch ( IOException ex) {
        sbError.append(ex.getMessage());
    }

    mainApp.addOutput(sbOutput.toString());
    mainApp.addError(sbError.toString());

    return;

}

    private class StreamGobblerOutput extends Thread {
        private InputStream is;
        private String outputPathPrefix;
        private StringBuilder sbOutput;
        private List<String> modifiedFileNames;
        private Scanner scanner;

        private StreamGobblerOutput(InputStream is, String outputPathPrefix) {
            this.is = is;
            this.outputPathPrefix = outputPathPrefix;
            sbOutput = new StringBuilder();
            modifiedFileNames = new ArrayList<String>();
            scanner = new Scanner(is);
        }

        public StringBuilder getOutput() {
            return sbOutput;    
        }

        public List<String> getModifiedFileNames() {
            return modifiedFileNames;       
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            //create pattern
            Pattern patternProgress = Pattern.compile("\\((\\d+)%\\)");

            //InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
            //BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
            String ligne = null;
            while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                ligne = scanner.nextLine();

                sbOutput.append(ligne);
                sbOutput.append("\r\n");
                //bw.write("\r\n");

                Matcher mProgress = patternProgress.matcher(ligne);
                if (mProgress.find()) {
                    int percentage = Integer.parseInt(mProgress.group(1));
                    System.err.println("percentage=" + percentage);
                    mainApp.mainWindowController.setProgressExecute(percentage/100.0);
                }
            }
            mainApp.mainWindowController.setProgressExecute(1.0);
            if (scanner != null) {
                scanner.close();
             }
        }
    }

    private class StreamGobblerError extends Thread {
        private InputStream is;
        private StringBuilder sbError;
        private Scanner scanner;

        private StreamGobblerError(InputStream is) {
            this.is = is;
            sbError = new StringBuilder();
            scanner = new Scanner(is);
        }

        public StringBuilder getErrors() {
            return sbError;     
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            //InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
            //BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
            String ligne = null;
            while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                ligne = scanner.nextLine();
                sbError.append(ligne);
                sbError.append("\r\n");
            }
            if (scanner != null) {
                scanner.close();
             }
        }
    }
```

Update: I tried redirecting the output to a file and reading from it, but it appears this runs into the same buffering problem as the previous implementation: I get only two data points.

As a workaround, I will have to ask the creator of the .exe to include 4100 extra characters in each line showing the progress.

Comment: Have you got access to the code of the process which generates output? Perhaps you can do flushes there on some interval of time/after n number of writes?

Comment: I do not have access to the code of the process i call, but when i call it from the console, it seems to output the progress indicator data one by one i.e.: it seems to be flushed after each data point.

Comment: @Adder - is the external program your are invoking C/C++ based ?

Comment: you can output the exe to a file then tail the file to check whether output the progress indicator one by one?

Comment: I tried redirecting it to file, but when i read the file, I have the buffering problem again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your external process is C/C++ (stdio) based, than this is most likely a block buffering issue:

> stdio-based programs as a rule are line buffered if they are running interactively in a terminal and block buffered when their stdout is redirected to a pipe. In the latter case, you won't see new lines until the buffer overflows or flushed.

see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20509641/2788297) for more details, and some possible workarounds.

Please also note that according to [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/86cebhfs.aspx), line buffering is not an option on Win32:

> **_IOLBF**
>   For some systems, this provides line buffering. However, for Win32, the behavior is the same as _IOFBF - Full Buffering.

so if you choose to modify the "exe" program to set a proper output mode with `setvbuf`, you would have to use:

```
_IONBF No buffer
```

instead.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. How would the C program need to be modified?

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Controlling-Buffering.html This way, i guess.

Comment: @Adder, yep, of see this links if this is a windows binary: [setvbuf](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/86cebhfs.aspx), but take a note that line buffering is not supported under win32.

Answer (score 0):

From the Javadocs

> Optionally, a PrintStream can be created so as to flush automatically;
>   this means that the flush method is automatically invoked after a byte
>   array is written, one of the println methods is invoked, or a newline
>   character or byte ('\n') is written.

Reference: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html

1. One way to do this is to have output stream flush() after every write.
   System.out.flush()
2. You could also define your own flushable PrintStream and use that.

Comment: My process generating the data points is not written in java and is only indirectly accessible to me..