# Get data every newline from endless loop (C program) in Haskell

Tags: haskell, websocket, yesod

I'm having trouble getting data every newline from standard ouput. Data is produced by C program. This is the C code:

```
// gcc counter.c -o counter

#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  unsigned int i = 0;
  while(1) {
    printf("%d\n", i);
    sleep(1);
    i++;
  }
}
```

My goal is to get the same behaviour as this haskell function below:

```
timeSource :: MonadIO m => Source m TL.Text
timeSource = forever $ do
    now <- liftIO getCurrentTime
    yield $ TL.pack $ show now
    liftIO $ threadDelay 1000000
```

I tried using `readProcess` and `readCreateProcess` from `System.Process` module. This is one of my tries:

```
counter :: MonadIO m => Source m TL.Text
counter = do
    r <- liftIO $ readCreateProcess (proc "./counter" []) ""
    -- r <- liftIO $ readProcess "./counter" [] [] 
    yield $ TL.pack $ show r
    liftIO $ threadDelay 1000000
```

This is how I use `counter` function within `webSockets`:

```
    webSockets $ race_
        (sourceWS $$ Data.Conduit.List.map TL.toUpper =$ sinkWSText)
        -- (timeSource $$ sinkWSText)
        (counter $$ sinkWSText)
```

When I open http://localhost:3000/, it doesn't work. Here's the complete code.

```
{-# LANGUAGE QuasiQuotes, TemplateHaskell, TypeFamilies, OverloadedStrings #-}

module Main where

import Yesod.Core
import Yesod.WebSockets
import qualified Data.Text.Lazy as TL
import Control.Monad (forever)
import Control.Concurrent (threadDelay)
import Data.Time
import Data.Conduit
import System.Process 
import qualified Data.Conduit.List

data App = App

instance Yesod App

mkYesod "App" [parseRoutes|
/ HomeR GET
|]

timeSource :: MonadIO m => Source m TL.Text
timeSource = forever $ do
    now <- liftIO getCurrentTime
    yield $ TL.pack $ show now
    liftIO $ threadDelay 1000000

counter :: MonadIO m => Source m TL.Text
counter = do
  r <- liftIO $ readCreateProcess (proc "./counter" []) ""
  -- r <- liftIO $ readProcess "./counter" [] [] 
  yield $ TL.pack $ show r
  liftIO $ threadDelay 1000000

getHomeR :: Handler Html
getHomeR = do
    webSockets $ race_
        (sourceWS $$ Data.Conduit.List.map TL.toUpper =$ sinkWSText)
        (timeSource $$ sinkWSText)
        -- (counter $$ sinkWSText)
    defaultLayout $
        toWidget
            [julius|
                var conn = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:3000/");
                conn.onopen = function() {
                    document.write("<p>open!</p>");
                    document.write("<button id=button>Send another message</button>")
                    document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", function(){
                        var msg = prompt("Enter a message for the server");
                        conn.send(msg);
                    });
                    conn.send("hello world");
                };
                conn.onmessage = function(e) {
                    document.write("<p>" + e.data + "</p>");
                };
                conn.onclose = function () {
                    document.write("<p>Connection Closed</p>");
                };
            |]

main :: IO ()
main = warp 3000 App
```

So my question is how to access data every `printf` in infinite loop and use it in Haskell?

**EDIT 1:**

Based on MathematicalOrchid's suggestion, here's what I did so far.

```
counter :: MonadIO m => Source m TL.Text
counter = do
  r <- liftIO $ createProcess (proc "./counter" []){ std_out = CreatePipe, std_in = CreatePipe}
  let (Just inp, Just outp, _, phandle) = r
  liftIO $ hSetBuffering outp LineBuffering
  contents <- liftIO $ hGetLine outp
  yield $ TL.pack $ show contents
  liftIO $ threadDelay 1000000
```

I suppose it's still *blocking* until the process terminates.

**EDIT 2:**

For testing if `createProcess` works I tried this.

```
counterTest :: IO ()
counterTest = do
  r <- createProcess (proc "./counter" []){ std_out = CreatePipe, std_in = CreatePipe}
  let (Just inp, Just outp, _, phandle) = r
  hSetBuffering outp LineBuffering
  contents <- hGetLine outp
  print contents
```

Apparently It's still blocking.

Comment: A blocking createProcess would not make any sense, so I strongly suspect this is not the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20504272/1276388) I must add `fflush(stdout);` to my C file.

**Here's my solution:**

```
// gcc counter.c -o counter

#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  unsigned int i = 0;
  while(1) {
    printf("%d\n", i);
    sleep(1);
    i++;
    fflush(stdout);
  }
}
```

And here's how I read a process in Haskell:

```
 ...
 import System.IO
 ...

counter :: MonadIO m => Source m TL.Text
counter = do
  r <- liftIO $ createProcess (proc "./counter" []){ std_out = CreatePipe, std_in = CreatePipe}
  let (_, Just outp, _, _) = r
  liftIO $ hSetBuffering outp LineBuffering
  forever $ do 
    contents <- liftIO $ hGetLine outp
    yield $ TL.pack $ show ("Stdout: " ++ contents)
    liftIO $ threadDelay 1000000 -- already put 1s delay in C file, so it's optional
  liftIO $ hClose outp
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Quoting the documentation for `readProcess`:

> `readProcess` forks an external process, reads its standard output strictly, **blocking until the process terminates**, and returns the output string. The external process inherits the standard error.

(Note emphasis.) It appears that `readCreateProcess` works similarly.

So basically when you call this function, it will sit there forever waiting for your external process to quit.

I suggest you use `proc` to create a `CreateProcess` structure as before, change `std_in` to be `CreatePipe`, and then call `createProcess` which should return you a handle that you can `hGetLine` from as required.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. It's still blocking, see my edit.

Comment: Hmm. Not sure what the problem is now... I've tried all the things I would have tried. Unless the problem is at the web end somehow...

Comment: I tried using `createProcess` in `IO ()` . Still blocking, see my edit. So I don't think the problem is at the web side.