# asyncio readline from c subprocess stdout seems to block on windows

Tags: python-3.x, windows, subprocess, stdout, python-asyncio

I'm on Windows 10.
I have a program written in c, that simply prints to the stdout and sleeps between prints, emulating some real work. I try to call this program from python (3.7.7) using asyncio and capture the prints to the program's stdout. I would expect that the prints are captured "real-time", however it seems that they are captured only at the end, when the c program has finished.

If I try to do the same thing with windows shell commands, it works, the prints to the stdout are captured as they are produced.

What am I missing? I would think that the stdout being forwarded to an asyncio subprocess pipe can be properly awaited on.

```c
/* cproc.c, compiled to cproc.exe */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

int main() {
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<3; i++) {
        printf("%i\n", i);
        Sleep(500);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

```py
import asyncio
import time

async def doit():
    # this does not work:
    command = ["cproc.exe"]
    # this works:
    command = [
        r"c:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe",
        "/c",
        "echo 1 & sleep 0.5 & echo 2 & sleep 0.5 & echo 3"
    ]
    proc = await asyncio.create_subprocess_exec(
        *command,
        stdout=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE
    )
    while True:
        data = await proc.stdout.readline()
        if data == b'':
            break
        line = data.decode('utf-8').rstrip()
        print(f"line @ {time.time()}: {line}")
    await proc.wait()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.ProactorEventLoop()
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    loop.run_until_complete(doit())
```

Outputs with calling cproc.exe, it can be seen that the lines were captured at the same moment:

```
line @ 1593940000.8466766: 0
line @ 1593940000.8466766: 1
line @ 1593940000.8466766: 2
```

Outputs with calling the windows shell commands, with proper timestamps:

```
line @ 1593939899.394881: 0
line @ 1593939900.402128: 1
line @ 1593939900.9687984: 2
```

Comment: this may be relevant as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2715847/read-streaming-input-from-subprocess-communicate/17698359#17698359

Comment: Thanks, @Adam.Er8 , this solves my problem indeed https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20503671/python-c-program-subprocess-hangs-at-for-line-in-iter